# Which AI model was used to create this video?

Tags: generative-model

I just stumbled upon [this hilarious youtube short](https://youtube.com/shorts/89TyGOt5zH8?si=l1aBv8tBOhWsHj5O) of Harry potter and his friends having a rave. I'd like to know which AI model was most likely used to create these images. Does anyone know?